# Rows are not beeing added to table- javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, web3js

I have here this code that gets me the latest pair from a smart contract:

```
document.getElementById("latestPairs").innerHTML = `<table class="table table-dark table-striped table-hover" id="latest"></table>`;
const table = document.getElementById("latest");
     const rowHeader = `<thead>
                            <tr>
                            <th>Token0</th>
                            <th>Token1</th>
                            <th>Pair</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>`
     table.innerHTML += rowHeader;


pcsfactoryC.events.PairCreated({fromBlock:'latest'})
.on('data', async function(event){
         //console.log(event.returnValues);
         // Do something here
    let pairs =  event.returnValues    
    let token0 = event.returnValues['token0'];
    let token1 = event.returnValues['token1'];
    let getPair = event.returnValues['pair'];
    console.log(token0 + " " + token1);
    add_row("latest", [event.returnValues['token0'], event.returnValues['token1'], event.returnValues['pair']]);

         
     })
     .on('error', console.error);
```

It works in the console as expected however the rows arent beeing added to the table and i receive following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: add_row is not defined
```

How can i fix this and make a dynamic table for my data?

Comment: `add_row()` isn't an inbuilt function. You have to define it. If you have defined it, can you please include it and update your question?

Comment: looks like i havent defined it, this 1 line of code is supposed to be the add_row function

Comment: can you please tell me how i can fix this, because i find no decent tutorials on youtube on how to do this with a dynamic table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply append innerHTML to table. Wrap each **row** with `<tr>` and each **column** with `<td>`.

```
function add_row(id, token0, token1, pair){
   var table = document.getElementById(id);
   const rowdata = "<tr><td>"+token0+"</td><td>"+token1+"</td><td>"+pair+"</td></tr>";
   table.innerHTML += rowdata;
}
```

add_row v2 (Insert to top instead of bottom)

```
function add_row(id, token0, token1, pair){
  var table = document.getElementById(id);
  
  var thead = document.querySelector('#'+id+' thead').innerHTML;

   const firstrowdata = "<tbody><tr><td>"+token0+"</td><td>"+token1+"</td><td>"+pair+"</td></tr></tbody>";
  const rowdata = "<tr><td>"+token0+"</td><td>"+token1+"</td><td>"+pair+"</td></tr>";
  
   if(table.rows.length == 1)table.innerHTML += firstrowdata;
  else{
    var tbody = document.querySelector('#'+id+' tbody').innerHTML;
    table.innerHTML = "<thead>"+ thead + "</thead>" + "<tbody>" + rowdata + tbody + "</tbody>";
  }
}
```

If you want to test it out, you need to change the way you call `add_row()`:

```
/* Removed outer [ ] after ("latest", */
add_row("latest", event.returnValues['token0'], event.returnValues['token1'], event.returnValues['pair']);
```

Comment: great this works, i got grey hair trying to get this btch to work dude, appreciate

Comment: the only thing i dont like is that the newest entries arent added to the top row but append - how can i turn this around?

Comment: I've added the function to insert row on top instead of bottom.

Comment: Hope it helped. Let me know if you still have any problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your own add_row function since it is not a built in function within js

Also the async function seems unnecessary since you are not using await.